# ELECTRON: Upload a PNG file (using PHP Web service)

Tags: php, web-services, file-upload, electron

I am building an electron app for multiple platforms. I need a standard (and reliable) way which upload a local PNG file to a web server using PHP.

I am sure what to do at PHP end, but not sure what is the best way to upload a Binary File using ELectron?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most basic way would be using Node API's for that.

First you need to use Node fs to load file content: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html then load file to Node's Buffer (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).

Then just convert it to Base64 (`buffer.toString('base64')`) or gzip it (https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) and send it to server via some POST method (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

This way it should be able to work with e.g. REST and other text based web services.